# if index > 0: loop; else: do only once (JSON & jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json, paging

I have been doing some customization to this jQuery paging script I found here
[Paging Through Records Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516754/paging-through-records-using-jquery)

I've got the paging working nicely, and it is handling different javascript responses appropriately.

I have one problem though. The response is expecting the JSON to have an index/array.

90% of the time, I have multiple entries in my JSON, but sometimes I have only one item being returned. This results in zero entries.

Here is the code I've got

```
var pagedContent = {
    data: null
    ,holder: null
    ,currentIndex : 0
    ,init: function(data, holder) {
        jQuery("body").data(holder,data);
        this.holder=holder;
        this.show(0, holder); // show last
    }
    ,show: function(index, holder) {
        this.data=jQuery("body").data(holder);
        if(!this.data){
          return;
        }
        var j=2;
        if(this.data.length-index&lt;=j){
          j=this.data.length-index-1;
        }
        var jsonObj = this.data[index];
        if(!jsonObj) {
          return;
        }
        var holdSubset="";
        for(i=0;i&lt;=j;i++){
          jsonObj=this.data[index+i];
          this.currentIndex = index;
          if(this.holder=="id1"){
            var theResultVariables = jsonObj.whatever
            var resultInput='&lt;div class="putstuff"&gt;'+theResultVariables+'&lt;/div&gt;';
          }
          if(this.holder=="id2"){
            var theResultVariables = jsonObj.whatever
            var resultInput='&lt;div class="putstuff2"&gt;'+theResultVariables+'&lt;/div&gt;';
          }
          holdSubset= holdSubset+resultInput;
        }

        jQuery("body").html("&lt;div id=\"counter\"&gt;"+parseFloat(index+1)+" to "+ parseFloat(index+j+1)+" of "+this.data.length+"&lt;/div&gt;"+holdSubset+"&lt;div class=\"prevNext\"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;");

        if(index!=0){
          var previous = jQuery("&lt;a &gt;").attr("href","#").click(this.previousHandler).text("&lt; previous").data("whichList",this.holder).data("thisIndex",index - 2-1);
          jQuery("body").append(previous);
        }

        if(index+i&lt;this.data.length){
          var next = jQuery("&lt;a class=\"next\"&gt;").attr("href","#").click(this.nextHandler).text("next &gt;").data("whichList",this.holder).data("thisIndex",index + 2 +1);
          jQuery("body").append(next);
        }
    }
    ,nextHandler: function() {
        pagedContent.show(jQuery(this).data("thisIndex"), jQuery(this).data("whichList"));
        return false;
    }
    ,previousHandler: function() {
        pagedContent.show(jQuery(this).data("thisIndex"), jQuery(this).data("whichList"));
        return false
    }
};
```

I know that I can add another  check

```
var jsonObj = this.data[index];
if(!jsonObj){
  var jsonObj=this.data;
}
if(!jsonObj) {
  return;
}
```

and then lower down

```
jsonObj=this.data[index+i];
if(!jsonObj){
  jsonObj=this.data;
}
```

But I don't think that is probably the most efficient way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: @pedalpete: I know it's tempting to post all of your code, but... don't. 95% (probably more) of the code you posted here has nothing to do with your actual problem. Still you're forcing everybody to read it through and come to this conclusion. Finding the minimal, *abstract* code sample that reproduces your issue helps everybody, including those that might have a similar problem in different shape and come here via search.

Comment: I actually did strip out a bunch of code, but may be not enough. I wanted to give enough context to not leave questions. I'm learning this balancing act. I'll try to do better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, take a look at ***[jQuery.makeArray](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.makeArray)***. It takes an array or a scalar, and returns an array. If you add a call like this in as a preceding step:

```
this.data = jQuery.makeArray(this.data);
```

You won't have to worry about if it's a scalar or an array. Scalars will be converted to arrays of length 1.